default values ignored in @main?
In Scala 3 I can specify a main method which gets one parameter like this:
@main def main(mode: String): Unit = ???

If I run it without specifying the argument, I would get “Illegal command line: more arguments expected”. Fine.
Now if I specify a default value like this
@main def main(mode: String = "foo"): Unit = ???

then I still get that same error.

Why is that?
And why doesn't the compiler complain if default
values are not possible in main method arguments? To just ignore them doesn't seem useful to me.

Tried with Scala 3.4.2.
Edit: submitted https://github.com/scala/scala3/issues/20485

It seems that the argument parsing machinery generated automatically doesn't handle default parameters. You may open an issue. Or just use a proper argument parsing library directly rather than rely on compiler magic.

Did you try with Options out of curiosity?

The argument parsing in the @main is completely useless. The only reasonable thing you can do is to get the old-fashioned String array and then parse it yourself with some proper library. There is no way how you can design a properly functioning interface using what the current @main provides, which is a pity...

I don't think it's described anywhere in the docs but from my experiments: @main assumes you have a very simple case, where fixed number of arguments (optionally with 1 vararg), all is which are primitives is enough. For anything more flexible (optional arguments, default values, subcommands) you have to use an external library. I'd use it for PoC to test most basic use case, and then migrate to something else. Or for very simple, single use case scripts.

Scala 3 main method parameters are good only for very basic cases, examples and such. For any real use be sure to use a dedicated library. There probably exist other, but the best known is mainargs. The current Scala 3 implementation is a subset of this library. See also Plan for @main and mainargs in Scala3? topic at scala-contributors:

The plan, after discussion in the SIP committee several months ago, is:

In Scala 3.0.0, ship a minimal @main support, that is a strict subset of mainargs and that the committee could build consensus on.
After 3.0.0, revisit and generalize it to support more use cases.


Perhaps the situation will change one Macro annotations will stabilize. Cf. this post in the same topic:

I believe the current plan is to build any extension on top of macro annotations, which have an experimental implementation.

